# Is the OpenFlow implementation platform dependent?

Tags: openflow

I want to know  is the OpenFlow implementation  dependent on the platform or the CPU architecture?  In other words can we run the same OpenFlow package on the windows and Linux? I saw that we can download the OpenFlow package and install it on the Linux but I want to know can I install that package on the windows platform too?

Answer (score 0):

Your question: "Can we run OpenFlow on both Windows and Linux?"
Is the same as asking: "Can we run HTTP on both Windows and Linux?"
And the simple asnwer is: "Yes you can"

OpenFlow is the specification of an device-to-controller communication protocol used in the SDN paradigm. OpenFlow is one example of a "South-bound" protocol between an SDN Controller, and an OpenFlow enabled network device.

So, when you ask if you can install the OpenFlow package on a windows platform, it depends. It depends on the implementation of the SDN controller. The SDN controller will probably have a south bound module which implements OpenFlow so that you can communicate with OpenFlow enabled devices. This south bound module with OpenFlow support is what you are asking for.

So, if the "OpenFlow package" you found were for Linux, you probably couldn't install that on windows.
That being said. There are several SDN controllers with OpenFlow support that can run on Windows. Including the massive, and highly functional, OpenDaylight controller. OpenDaylight is implemented in Java, and can therefore run on both Linux, Windows, OS X etc..

Comment: @user3201263 please confirm the answer if you find it acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Once you let another server(here we call it controller) to determine the packet forwarding behavior of your local machine (here it is your PC), it turns into so-called SDN mechanism. So it's not relevant what kind of CPU or hardware you are choosing, basically, you can consider SDN as a software solution.

However, it does not mean it has no any dependence on the platform, especially when we talk about windows. The problem is that when you delegate the forwarding behavior to the controller, do you have the privilege to do this? Basically it means it needs to program on the kernel level which you cannot obtain in windows platform.

So please forget to do this on Windows unless the Richmond company implements this by themselves.